# Dropdown/select inside messagebox in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I would like to have a dropdown/select thing inside my msgbox in c#. Like this one[image]

But to select color theme.

I have tried the following

```
string[] items = {"Black", "White", "Red", "Green", "Blue"};
string msg = "Select one color theme you like to have active", items;
string title = "Select color theme";
messagebox buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
DialogResult result;
result = MessageBox.Show(msg, title, buttons);
```

But its not working. Do u know any solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MessageBox is a foraign class where you not can add additional controls. You have to build the Control by yourself.

```
var form = new Form(); // or control how you like
var dropDown = new ComboBox();
// some dropdown settings ....
string[] installs = new string[]{"Typical", "Compact", "Custom"};
dropDown .Items.AddRange(installs);
form.Controls.Add(dropDown);

// start/show the control
form.Show();
```

[ComboBox Docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdown?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Oh, now I see what I messed up, pretty simple. Thanks for explaining up so clearly :) appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way will be to create a custom form then use .ShowDialog()

Comment: I see.. thanks for helping me, appreciate that. But next time (if you know how, want and can) try to explain more clearly :) no hate, ty